# Unity android plugin: problems with resources

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

I'm developing an android plugin for Unity that uses zxing as library.

My app crashes when at `OnCreate` on an Activity which extends `CaptureActivity` due to missing resources (`R.id.` stuff).

I have placed the zxing project in `Plugins/Android`, as for the other plugins. It finds classes (I managed to list all classes in apk and they are there, even cativities can be started), but there must be some kind of problem when creating layouts as it fails there.

If I surround `onCreate` with `try... catch`, then the scanning activity starts and works, but there are no menus, icons, buttons...

I tried creating a .jar in eclipse and then replace the entire project in Unity by it, but it doesn't work either.

I'm using facebook plugin as well, and it works properly. The project structure is as usual: project placed in `Plugins\Android` and that's all.

Why is facebook project working fine and mine not? I can't understand.

I already solved other problems by reimporting the stuff, and some months ago I managed to make zxing work in another project, but now I can't (maybe updates have something to do)

For now my only option is to get resources by name: `getResources().getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage)`. It would work, despite of the lot of work, as I'm not going to modify anything else in ZXing, but not the best option, and definitively not a general solution to work with plugins.

Any help, or documentation in deep unity android plugins stuff is welcome.

PS: I added sources to unity plugins folder, so I can edit with Eclipse with no need to compile, copy and all that stuff. I can't do that for ZXing as unity creates a bunch of .meta files that makes R generation fail (files can be ignored applying patterns in code folders, but R generation is done by a different processor and I was not able to set any filter), so I have to copy the project from eclipse to unity when modified.

Comment: Hey man were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Not yet, sorry. I'm working on different stuff for now, but I'll update this thread when I'm back to it if I finally solve the issue.